# How to Find the Mass of an Individual Element in a Compound/Molecule

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry, mole

What is the procedure/math for finding the mass of a specific element in a substance? For instance, how many grams of Oxygen are in 6.8 grams of Epinephrine (Adrenaline)?

Comment: Do you understand molar masses an chemical formulas? If yes, then what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is I don't understand the (in the example I posted) relationship between the molar mass of Oxygen, and the entire actual mass of the adrenaline sample. How do you find the actual mass of oxygen in grams in the sample?

Comment: take one molecule of epinephrine and find the mass percent of oxygen(mass oxygen/total mass). Then multiply result with 6.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1: Find the Molar Mass of Adrenaline**

To do this, you must need to know its chemical formula which is $\ce{C9H13NO3}$. Now to calculate its molar mass, we add up all of the molar masses of each atom: $$M =9\times12~\mathrm{g~mol^{-1}} + 1\times13~\mathrm{g~mol^{-1}} + 14~\mathrm{g~mol^{-1}} + 3\times16~\mathrm{g~mol^{-1}} = 183~\mathrm{g~mol^{-1}}$$

**Step 2: Find the Mass of Oxygen in 1 mol of Adrenaline**

In each molecule of adrenaline, there is 3 molecules of oxygen atoms. This means that in $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of adrenaline, there are $3\ \mathrm{mol}$ of oxygen. Therefore the mass of oxygen in $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of adrenaline is: $\mathrm{3~mol\times16~g~mol^{-1} = 48~g}$.

**Step 3: Calculate Percentage Composition of Oxygen by Mass**

We now know that in every mole of adrenaline, there are $48\ \mathrm{g}$ of oxygen. We also know that $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of adrenaline weighs $183\ \mathrm{g}$. Therefore in $183\ \mathrm{g}$ of adrenaline, there are $48\ \mathrm{g}$ of oxygen. All have to do is simply divide by them by each other and multiply by $100$ to get the percentage composition of oxygen. Therefore the percentage composition is $26.23\,\%$.

**Step 4: Calculate Mass of Oxygen in Sample**

Now we know the percentage composition of oxygen which is $26.23\,\%$. This means that in every gram of adrenaline, there is $0.2623\ \mathrm{g}$ of oxygen. Therefore to find the mass of oxygen in the sample: $$m_\text{oxygen} = 0.2623 \times 6.8~\mathrm{g} = 1.78~\mathrm{g}$$